# Can't rename remote branch

Tags: git, github

I want to rename a remote branch from **research_mvp** to **research**

First, I rename local branch

```
[research_mvp]> git branch -m research_mvp research
```

Second, I delete the remote branch

```
[research]> git push origin :research_mvp
```

Third, I push up new branch

```
[research]> git push --set-upstream origin research
```

This makes a new remote branch with the old remote branch name.

```
* [new branch]      research -> research_mvp
```

Why does it use the name of the old branch instead of the name of the new branch I pushed up?

Comment: Have you tried ```git push -f ...``` to overwrite the remote repository with yours?

Comment: Have not tried but `git push -u origin research:research` could work. Also look at `branch.research.merge` in `git config`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you renamed the branch, you keep the reference to the remote branch for pushing.  When you did the `git push --set-upstream origin reference`, it did not change the remote in the `.git/config` file.  Part of the problem is likely that git still thinks that `origin/research_mvp` still exists.

You might be able to fix it by running `git fetch --prune`.  Git will update itself to realize that `origin/research_mvp` doesn't exist anymore.  It doesn't remove these relationships when you delete the remote branch.  Then running the `git push --set-upstream origin reference` should work properly.

Another option would be to create a new branch and do a fresh push.

```
git checkout research
git branch -m research research_temp
git checkout research_temp
git checkout -b research
git branch -d research_temp
git push -u origin research
```